# Why is Name an invalid attribute to search for or retrieve, while searching for an email

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap

So I wrote some C# code, content irrelevant because I will be sharing the SOAP request and reply, to query for and retrieve an email based on its name.

Request:

```
<s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
        <RetrieveRequest>
            <ObjectType>Email</ObjectType>
            <Properties>Name</Properties>
            <Filter xsi:type="SimpleFilterPart">
                <Property>Name</Property>
                <SimpleOperator>equals</SimpleOperator>
                <Value>a2e1fccb-1a78-47bf-adba-269ed9e65c26</Value>
            </Filter>
        </RetrieveRequest>
    </RetrieveRequestMsg>
</s:Body>
```

Reply:

```
<soap:Body>
    <RetrieveResponseMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
        <OverallStatus>Error: Invalid column name 'Name'.</OverallStatus>
        <RequestID>359db689-4bcd-4f04-850f-2dca0ba4dff2</RequestID>
    </RetrieveResponseMsg>
</soap:Body>
```

The name was an accpeted attribute when I was creating the email:

Request:

```
<s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <CreateRequest xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
        <Options/>
        <Objects xsi:type="Email">
            <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
            <CustomerKey>a2e1fccb-1a78-47bf-adba-269ed9e65c26</CustomerKey>
            <Name>a2e1fccb-1a78-47bf-adba-269ed9e65c26</Name>
            <CategoryID>2245322</CategoryID>
            <HTMLBody>&lt;center&gt;&lt;h2&gt;Way Cool Email&lt;/h2&gt;&lt;/center&gt;</HTMLBody>
            <TextBody>Sample body</TextBody>
            <Subject>Sent on Saturday, May 17, 2014 at 1:20 PM</Subject>
            <CharacterSet>iso-8859-1</CharacterSet>
        </Objects>
    </CreateRequest>
</s:Body>
```

Reply:

```
<soap:Body>
    <CreateResponse xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
        <Results>
            <StatusCode>OK</StatusCode>
            <StatusMessage>Created Email.</StatusMessage>
            <OrdinalID>0</OrdinalID>
            <NewID>46198</NewID>
            <Object xsi:type="Email">
                <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
                <ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
                <CustomerKey>a2e1fccb-1a78-47bf-adba-269ed9e65c26</CustomerKey>
                <Name>a2e1fccb-1a78-47bf-adba-269ed9e65c26</Name>
                <CategoryID>2245322</CategoryID>
                <HTMLBody>&lt;center&gt;&lt;h2&gt;Way Cool Email&lt;/h2&gt;&lt;/center&gt;</HTMLBody>
                <TextBody>Sample body</TextBody>
                <Subject>Sent on Saturday, May 17, 2014 at 1:20 PM</Subject>
                <CharacterSet>iso-8859-1</CharacterSet>
            </Object>
        </Results>
        <RequestID>76d5b933-cf81-447d-b611-58393c59a6eb</RequestID>
        <OverallStatus>OK</OverallStatus>
    </CreateResponse>
</soap:Body>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You may have already seen this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9381437/how-to-retrieve-an-exacttarget-email but if you haven't the comment on the answer may be of some help.

Comment: Do you know what type of account you have?  I tested again with your code and it worked just fine - the above solution would make sense if it were an Enterprise 2.0 account.  It's also not the best way to approach it.  Let me know if you have E2.0.

Comment: Good question. I am currently on a Sandbox Environment for Enterprise 1.0. What better way do you speak off?

Comment: Trying to reproduce the error - so far no luck.  What endpoint are you using?

Comment: Still investigating - but so far unable to reproduce.

Comment: @KellyJAndrews Darn, let me know if WebEx would help

Comment: I have nothing still - I would suggest sending this to global support and see what they say - probably needs some deeper investigation. We can add the answer here once we can get it sorted.